# Finding all of the earliest dates and showing them in a msg box

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that finds the student with the earliest date in my sheet and it shows some information about that student. But the problem is this sub only shows one of the students. I have more than one student with the same earliest date and i want to show all of them in a msg box. Can anyone help me with this problem. Thanks in advance! :)

```
Sub FindMin()
Dim Mn As Long
Mn = Application.Match(Application.Min(Range("D1:D18289")), Range("D1:D18289"), 0)

MsgBox ("For the oldest students: " & Range("D" & Mn) & " the following applies: 
PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME: " & Range("k" & Mn) & ", STUDENT_ID: " & Range("L" & Mn) & " and Convertet ENROLL_PERIOD: " & Range("M" & Mn))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would find the minimum value and then loop through all of the rows.

This could be sped up by using an array to loop through as well but depending on the size of your data set that may not be needed.

```
Sub FindMin()
    Dim minValue As Date
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    minValue = Application.Min(Cells(1, 4).EntireColumn)
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 4) = minValue Then
            MsgBox ("For the oldest students: " & Cells(i, 4) & " the following applies: PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME: " & Cells(i, 11) & ", STUDENT_ID: " & Cells(i, 12) & " and Convertet ENROLL_PERIOD: " & Cells(i, 13))
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

I would also suggest including a way to leave the loop incase you don't want to view them all since MessageBox can get annoying. To do this is pretty straight forward

```
Sub FindMin()
    Dim minValue As Date
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim text As String

    minValue = Application.Min(Cells(1, 4).EntireColumn)
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 4) = minValue Then
            text = "For the oldest students: " & Cells(i, 4) & " the following applies: PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME: " & Cells(i, 11) & ", STUDENT_ID: " & Cells(i, 12) & " and Convertet ENROLL_PERIOD: " & Cells(i, 13)
            If MsgBox(text, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your answers! They were very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use `FIND()` or a loop:

```
Sub FindMin()
    Dim Mn As Long, oldest As Date, msg As String

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        oldest = .Min(Range("D1:D18289"))
    End With

    msg = ""
    For Mn = 1 To 18289
        If Cells(Mn, "D").Value = oldest Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & "For the oldest students: " & Range("D" & Mn) & " the following applies: PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME: " & Range("k" & Mn) & ", STUDENT_ID: " & Range("L" & Mn) & " and Convertet ENROLL_PERIOD: " & Range("M" & Mn)
        End If
    Next Mn

    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

This gets you a single `MsgBox()` that includes all the results.

Answer (score 0):

Another method using AutoFilter:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rMinCell As Range
    Dim dMin As Double
    Dim sDate As String
    Dim sText As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    dMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(ws.Columns("D"))
    sDate = Format(dMin, ws.Range("D2").NumberFormat)

    sText = "For the oldest students: " & sDate & " the following applies:" & Chr(10)

    With ws.Range("D1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, sDate
        For Each rMinCell In .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
            sText = sText & Chr(10) & "PROGRAM_TYPE_NAME: " & ws.Cells(rMinCell.Row, "K").Value & ", STUDENT_ID: " & ws.Cells(rMinCell.Row, "L").Value & " and Convertet ENROLL_PERIOD: " & ws.Cells(rMinCell.Row, "M").Value & Chr(10)
        Next rMinCell
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    MsgBox sText

End Sub
```